# How to pass the value from one function to another function in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var one;      
    $('#button2').click(function () {    
        one = "hello";
    });
    $('#button3').click(function () {    
        alert(one);
    });    
});
```

I cannot get values in that variable called "one"..
its shows "undefined value"
Please help me ...

I always click button3 after button 2..

Comment: What you have there will work provided you click `button2` before you click `button3`.

Comment: Separately: Using proper code indentation (any of the major styles is fine) makes your code clearer -- clearer to you, and clearer to the people you're asking help from. I've fixed it for you on this occasion.

Comment: Works for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jMMut/)

Comment: always click button3 after button 2..

Comment: yeah me too.thank you friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `assign a default value for one` before use it,

What happens you are `defining` it but not `assigns` any `value` in it. And `clicking` on `button3` before clicking on `button2`, to work your code you must have to `click` on `button2` first then click `button3`

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/oriMuFU/1/)

**Otherwise** `assign` a value to `variable one` when declaring it. like

```
var one=""; // alerts blank not undefined
```

Comment: *"You hve to initialize one before use it,"* No, you don't. Declaring it initializes it to the value `undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean to say `assign` updating...

Answer (score 1):

You get value undefined because you have just declared variable not defined.

`var one = "";` will not give you undefined.

You need to assign some value to it. Because "hello" will be assigned to one only if `#button2` is clicked.

Comment: oh..ok but I want to pass my values from button2 fuction to button3 function ???? what to do??

Comment: @user2975952: As I said, your code is **already** doing that. Both of your event handler functions close over the `one` variable, so both have access to it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes exactly